# How to save a regex to a buffer in Unix?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a set of frequently used regexes. And I want to save them to buffer so that I can use it whenever needed. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to put a LOT more effort into asking your question. Right now it could mean just about anything. Clarify, explain, give an example, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify, I assume you're at the Unix prompt...

You can just assign them to variables:

```
> var="Hello, world!"
> echo $var
```

Then whenever you need to reference the variable, use the dollar sign with the variable name.  Also, if you want to include it in a string, you need to using double-quotes; single-quotes take their contents literally without evaluating for variables.

Here's an example with `grep` (since you tagged your question for `grep`):

```
grep $MyExpression file
```

It should be noted that these variables won't persist between shell sessions unless you set these up in the [*rc file (or other startup script) for your shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file).

Also, you could always write a shell script.